# "Page not found" error when running symfony 4.4 web server in docker

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, symfony4

I'm having troubles with docker which I'm beginning to learn.
I know I won't use symfony web server in production, in a real life project, but for now, symfony web server is what I need. Just so you know, when I run symfony server:start command line outside of docker, everything works fine. All routes are ok.
The problem comes when I try using the web server with docker. No routes are found. Even this one : "/" .
Here's my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  app:
    container_name: app
    build: 
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/app/
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:10.2
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DATA_HOST=${POSTGRES_DATA_HOST}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
```

And here's the Dockerfile

```
FROM php:zts-buster

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    wget \
    sudo \
    libpq-dev \ 
    nano

# composer is installed globally in directory user/bin. The command is named composer
RUN curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer

RUN wget https://get.symfony.com/cli/installer -O - | bash && \
    mv /root/.symfony/bin/symfony /usr/local/bin/symfony

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_pgsql

WORKDIR /app/
COPY ./ /app/

RUN composer install

CMD [ "symfony", "serve", "--port=8000", "&&", "symfony", "open:local"]
```

Could you help figure out what's wrong with my config ?
Many thanks for your help !!

EDIT :
Here's the docker container logs. It doesn't say much.

```
[WARNING] run "symfony server:ca:install" first if you want to run the web server with TLS support, or use "--no-tls" to avoid this warning                                                                                         
Tailing Web Server/PHP log file                                                                   
 [OK] Web server listening                                                      
      http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

Just in case, I actually run the above command, but I still have this warning

Answer (score 0):

Please could you add the logs of the docker container ? If the container is not running, you can still check the logs using -a option.

```
docker ps -a
docker logs <CONTAINER_ID>
```

In Docker container, you can't use localhost to connect to the database as it refer to the container itself. You need to use the container name of postgres, so `postgres:<port>`

**EDIT:**

In the Dockerfile, you add the current directory in the image /app/, then you map the current directory to /app in docker-compose.yml. You should remove the mapping docker-compose, the content of current directory will replace the content of /app/ in the container. You can check the content of /app with the command:

```
docker exec app ls -l /app/
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Cyril. As you will see, logs doesn't say much. I'm sorry, I didn't understand the part with postgres. I'll checkout examples of docker-compose on the internet to clear that out.

Answer (score 0):

I finally used this config: https://github.com/symfony/cli/issues/183 .
It works but I can't understand what's wrong with mine. I tried mixing his config with mine, step by step, but it won't work.
After that, I had troubles with postgresql. I had this error : "could not connect to server: Connection refused. Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432". I solved it by replacing in the .env file the "127.0.0.1" part of database_url by my postgres service name in docker-compose.yml . Thanks for your help Cyril !